# Magento: can the catalog_product_flat tables hold multiple values per attribute?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

(Magento EE 1.9)

If I have a product with an attribute "color", and multiple values are selected for that attribute, can the catalog_product_flat table hold all of these multiple values at once?

For example, if I sell [this ball](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uph3e.jpg), it will have both "red" and "yellow" selected for its color.

I have done this, and reindexed, but my catalog_product_flat table is only holding the first selected value (e.g. "red").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to perform a full re-index. Reindexing attributes wasn't enough. Lesson learned. Also make sure your attributes aren't being overridden on a per-store-view basis.